# CommandEventArgs and Event question

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I generated a few buttons and attached to them an eventhandler like this:

```
Button pgs = new Button();//Create New Topic
pgs.Width = 20;
pgs.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click;
pgs.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
pgs.Text = tPage.ToString();
btns.Add(tPage.ToString());
buttons.Add(pgs);
}

void obtainTopicsPerPage_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in tPages)
    {
        if (item.Key == e.CommandName)
        {
            foreach (var posts in item.Value)
            {
                posts.ExecuteAll();
             }
        }
    }
    MyButtonTable();
}
```

Now, the eventhandler never triggers when i click on the button. i check with the debugger,,and when i click the button, there is only a postback,,but it doesnt reach inside the eventhandler functoin

**Update:**

```
    void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Button> btn=(List<Button>)ViewState["Buttons"];
    foreach (var item in btn)
    {
            item.Width = 20;
            item.Command += obtainTopicsPerPage_Click; //resigning the eventhandlers from the begining
             item.CommandName = tPage.ToString();
             item.Text = tPage.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you hooking up the button events again after post back?

Comment: shouldnt it be pgs.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.obtainTopicsPerPage_Click); ?

Comment: not really, Renius...,,no i dont WraithNath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often the case when dynamically generating the buttons. When the page posts back, the page doesn't have the buttons any more and therefore can't bind them to the event handlers.

The simplest solution is to make sure you re-generate all the buttons in the Page_Init on every load of the page.

Comment: But the buttons I generate is a list, which is generated dynamically through the code..The are generated depending on how many posts there are in the forum... should i save the list to a view state and then put it in the page_init...to be iterated?

Comment: You can use the same code that you used to generate the original list of buttons. You just need to make sure it runs on EVERY page_init so that the buttons are always there. If the buttons are likely to have changed between the first load and postback then you may want to store the dynamic data in viewstate in order to build the original set of buttons again. All in all though, the key is just to rebuild them all.

Comment: So how do i conserve their eventshandlers...Is doing like this enough? see my question update above